# unexpected motion

Tags: game-engine, physics, motion-capture

I downloaded an open source character in order to use it in a Blender Game. This character contains a body and an armature.
The issue is :
when I put physic type as character and run Blender game engine, the character moves alone very fast and very far from my scene. I can't find what is causing that. I would like him to just fall on the floor...

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

do you have any weapons or other objects attached or touching him? If so set those objects to no collision. I had the same problem when i first made my first game. He should no longer fly away from the scene. Also, make sure he is set to character physics.

Regards, Elijah. (p.s. hope this helps. If not tell me please and provide me with the .blend file and I'll work it out.)

Comment: Hi Elijah, Thanks for your answer.
As I know there is no weapon. There is just a walk implemented with keyframes brut even if I delete it, it's still the same.